# sonar installation on windows 7 and sql server 2014

Tags: sql-server, windows, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I tried to install `sonarqube 6.5` on windows 7 by using MS SQL server 2014.
But It failed. On my web log it says;

> "..
>   2017.09.12 14:22:36 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Background initialization failed. Stopping SonarQube
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Custom Analyzer [ındex_words_analyzer] failed to find filter under name [word_filter]
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.CustomAnalyzerProvider.build(CustomAnalyzerProvider.java:76)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.AnalysisService.(AnalysisService.java:216)
>   ..."

I redownload `sonarqube 6.5.zip` (in case of the corrupted file) but it did not change the situation.

I also tried to install `SonarQube 5.6.6 (LTS *)`, I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I changed my regional and language settings to English.
(Control Panel->Clock, Language, and Region->egion and Language->
Administrative->Change System Locale->English(US).)
Then restarted my computer, that solved my problem.